# Playing multiple sound processes through different audio devices

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio, process, speakers

I often watch a live stream on my TV, which I've connected to my Windows 7 PC through HDMI and play a game at the same time on my computer. Now, I'd like the stream-relevant sound (the one coming from chrome.exe) to play through the TV (as that's where the image is) and the game sound to come out through my laptop's speakers.

Now do note that I'm using a laptop. I often move around my computer and thus unplug the HDMI. This means that it has to be easy to set up each time.

Thank you in advance,
Jonatan

EDIT: I've looked into Vista Audio Changer but it doesn't seem to have what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use NirCmd. Check the 'setappvolume' command. You can specify the application, sound level and output device.

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd2.html